# bad alloc in QuickSort

Tags: c++

I'm doing QuickSort but i'm getting bad_alloc() error.Sometimes code run perfectly but some time i'm getting error.The program run perfectly and do sort right but only when it's run but s out of 4 times it's give me bad _alloc error.
so what's the problem???????

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void quicksort(int *a,int,int);
int main()
{
int i,j,*a;
a = new int[j];
cout<<"Enter the total element:";
cin>>j;
for(i=0;i<j;i++){
    cout<<"Enter element:";cin>>a[i];
}
quicksort(a,0,j-1);
cout<<"After sorting."<<endl;
for(i=0;i<j;i++){
    cout<<a[i]<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
void quicksort(int *a,int u,int d){
    int key = a[u];
    int upper = u;
    int lower = d;
    while(key>a[u] && u<lower){
        u++;
    }
    while(key<a[d] && d>upper){
        d--;
    }
    if(u<d){
    swap(a[u],a[d]);
    quicksort(a,upper,lower);
    }
    if(u>=d){
        swap(key,a[d]);
        if(upper!=d)
        {
        quicksort(a,upper,d-1);
        }
        if(d!=lower)
        {
        quicksort(a,d+1,lower);
        }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Move the statement

```
a = new int[j];
```

after

```
cin>>j;
```

You are allocating with "junk" as j takes the value whatever in the local stack memory location have!

Comment: 'j' at that point is uninitialized with an indeterminate value.